# Why are periodic functions through space disregarded in quantum mechanics?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, normalization

My question is a general question arising from an observation from the wavefunction of a free particle.

One must disregard, for a free particle, that the spatial wavefunction is:

$$\psi(x) = \sum_n A_n \ e^{ik_nx}$$

Because this is a Fourier sum, which implies that the constructed function will be periodic in space regardless of shape. Why is this impossible for a free particle? One may say that it's non-normalizable, which is likely true, but what if the integral of the function was equal to $1$? Is this strictly impossible due to the fact that it only *could* be possible if the function didn't repeat itself for each $\Delta x = \lambda$, but instead, for instance, had an exponentially shrinking area as one goes further down the number line? But due to the fact that the function must repeat its shape each time, an infinite area under the curve will always result?

Similarly, is the only reason a Fourier sum can represent bound states is because of the rule that is applied to $k$ and the given boundary conditions? For instance, for the infinite square well, given $k = \frac{n \pi}{L}$ where $L$ is the length of the well, and the fact that for each $\psi _n (x)$ that is used to create $\psi(x)$, $\psi _n$ must obey $\psi_n(0) = \psi_n(L) = 0$ where $k = \frac{n \pi}{L}$? Or is it because no wavefunction can exist except for the region $0 \le x \le a$ because the potential is infinite elsewhere and thus no solutions exist in that region other than $\psi = 0$?

Comment: afaik it is impossible to represent a particle because there is equal probabilty for the particle to be anywhere, whereas by "particle" we mean localized at an (x,y,z,t) and that is why wave packets are used http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Waves/wpack.html to represent particles

Comment: Is this really a different question than https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/438670/considering-an-arbitrary-wavefunction-for-a-free-particle-are-all-normalizable ?